# How can I get the Navionics App for iphone to utilise a third party gps

Tags: gps, navigation

When I am outside of wifi and cell coverage, or even by choice, how can you use a third party GPS?

Answer (score 1):

From the [frequently asked questions](http://www.navionics.com/en/faq/406) page, it appears Navionics has not tested third party GPS devices:

> Q. If I attach an external GPS to my iPod Touch 2nd Generation, will I locate my position on the Navionics app?
>
> A. Navionics has not tested this thoroughly enough to guarantee a good performance.

The answer suggests third party GPS devices should just work, but may not be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look in to Bad Elf Pro. It connects to the iPad/iPhone using Bluetooth.

Here is a link I found:
http://store.fugawi.com/products/bad-elf-gps-pro-for-ipod-touch-iphone-ipad